# Serialize multidimensional form data into a JSON object-array to work with application/json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am building a Laravel application. In the back-end, the `$controller->wantsJson()` method is `TRUE` if the content type of the request is `application/json`. So, to satisfy this, my jQuery AJAX call is this.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:        "POST",
    method:      "PUT",
    url:         $form.attr('action'),
    data:        $form.serialize(),
    dataType:    "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

This correctly triggers the `wantsJson()` response I need. The problem then is that jQuery cannot supply POST data as an `application/json` correctly. It tries to write it as a query string, which doesn't work for the PHP backend when it receives that content type.

To satisfy this, I need to stringify a JavaScript object-array into the `data` field.

```
JSON.stringify(dataObj)
```

So now the problem is, I don't have a concise way of turning a multidimensional form into an object-array. If I just try to convert the output of `$.serializeArray()`, I get this, which isn't able to be interpreted by the backend.

```
{
    'something' : 1,
    'field[foo]' : 2,
    'field[bar][]' : "a",
    'field[bar][]' : "b",
    'field[bar][]' : "c",
}
```

And that of course doesn't work. I need some sort of RegEx parser that can convert this form ...

```
<input name="something" value="1" />
<input name="field[foo]" value="2" />
<input name="field[bar][]" value="a" />
<input name="field[bar][]" value="b" />
<input name="field[bar][]" value="c" />
```

Into ...

```
{
    'something' : 1,
    'field'     : {
        'foo'   : 2,
        'bar'   : [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
        ]
    }
}
```

You'd expect something like this to exist already, but I can't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: In jQuery 'type' is just an alias to 'method'. You shouldn't need both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem but this package did the trick: [jQuery Serialize Object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object)

It's easy to use, just call this on your form (after loading the script)

```
$('form#contact').serializeJSON(); // to get the form as a JS object
```

Comment: this will only return key values pairs, not exactly as a nested object.

Comment: What do you mean @AryehArmon ? Have you checked the docs for  [jQuery Serialize Object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) ?

Comment: sorry my bad i thought it was serializeArray

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @mdamia
Here is the snippet with more detail.

After `JSON.stringify(dataObj);` You will get a json string as below:

**JSON:**

```
[
   {
      "name":"something",
      "value":"1"
   },
   {
      "name":"field[foo]",
      "value":"2"
   },
   {
      "name":"field[bar][]",
      "value":"a"
   },
   {
      "name":"field[bar][]",
      "value":"b"
   },
   {
      "name":"field[bar][]",
      "value":"c"
   }
]
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
//your raw json string
$rawData = '[{"name":"something","value":"1"},{"name":"field[foo]","value":"2"},{"name":"field[bar][]","value":"a"},{"name":"field[bar][]","value":"b"},{"name":"field[bar][]","value":"c"}]';

$json = json_decode($rawData);

$string = '';
foreach($json as $key => $val){
    $string .= $val->name.'='.$val->value.'&';
}

parse_str(rtrim($string,'&'),$data);

//var_dump($data);
echo json_encode($data); //your requied data
?>
```

//Output

```
{
   "something":"1",
   "field":{
      "foo":"2",
      "bar":[
         "a",
         "b",
         "c"
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  PHP [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

> parse_str — Parses the string into variables

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Hope this help.